# Javascript compare results in a single object array and append if a value matches within the same object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm looking to try and concatenate the array down to the base folder hierarchy.

In my example below "Level 1" is the lowest level there are no children folders to this level.
The "other level" will have a multitude of different folders all under the "Top Level"

The array I have the data is as follows:

```
[{ id: "Top Level", outerpath: "test plan", innerpath: "Regression" },
 { id: "other level", outerpath: "Regression", innerpath: "area 1" },
 { id: "Level 1", outerpath: "area 1", innerpath: "Subarea 1" },
 { id: "Level 1", outerpath: "area 1", innerpath: "Subarea 2" },
 { id: "Level 1", outerpath: "Regression", innerpath: "area 2" }]
```

Now I needing the results of the concaternation of the data within the object array to look like this:

```
test plan/Regression/area 1/Subarea 1
test plan/Regression/area 1/Subarea 2
test plan/Regression/area 2
```

However I have no clue how to start this. Perhaps its along the lines of a loop through the array matching "innerpath" and "outpath" values then pushing the completed data to another array?

Any ideas would be really useful.

UPDATE:

To expand on my question the array is dynamic and depending of the results of the API it might be like this array

```
[{ id: "Top Level", outerpath: "test plan", innerpath: "Regression" }
{ id: "other level", outerpath: "Regression", innerpath: "area 1" }
{ id: "Level 1", outerpath: "area 1", innerpath: "Subarea 1" }
{ id: "other level", outerpath: "area 1", innerpath: "Subarea 2" }
{ id: "Level 1", outerpath: "Regression", innerpath: "area 2" }
{ id: "Top Level", outerpath: "test plan", innerpath: "other testing" }
{ id: "Level 1", outerpath: "other testing", innerpath: "other testing area 1" }
{ id: "other level", outerpath: "other testing", innerpath: "other testing area 2" }
{ id: "Level 1", outerpath: "other testing area 2", innerpath: "other testing subarea 1" }
{ id: "Level 1", outerpath: "Subarea 2", innerpath: "SubSubArea 1" }]
```

So there isn't going to be just one top level it could be multiple top levels as the folder "test plan" will have multiple folders with some of them with subfolders of their own.

[image]

My code that collated the data from the callback from the API call is here:

```
let testSuiteData = res;
           testSuiteData.value.forEach(async testSuiteItem => {
                  console.log(testSuiteItem);
    
                  if(!testSuiteItem.hasChildren === true) // Level 1
                  {
                      console.log(testSuiteItem.parentSuite.name + '/' + testSuiteItem.name)
                      folderHierarchy.path.push({
                          id: 'Level 1',
                          outerpath: testSuiteItem.parentSuite.name,
                          innerpath: testSuiteItem.name
                      })
                            
                  }
                  else if(testSuiteItem.hasChildren === true ) // other levels
                  {
                      if(testSuiteItem.parentSuite.name === testSuiteItem.plan.name) // Top Level
                      {
                          console.log(testSuiteItem.parentSuite.name + '/' + testSuiteItem.name)
                          folderHierarchy.path.push({
                              id: 'Top Level',
                              outerpath: testSuiteItem.parentSuite.name,
                              innerpath: testSuiteItem.name
                          })
                      }
                      else{ // Other Levels
                          console.log(testSuiteItem.parentSuite.name + '/' + testSuiteItem.name)
                          folderHierarchy.path.push({
                              id: 'other level',
                              outerpath: testSuiteItem.parentSuite.name,
                              innerpath: testSuiteItem.name
                          })
                      }
                  }
    
                        
                  console.log(folderHierarchy.path);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the last entry (with `area 2`) be on `other level`? I'd try creating a tree structure from the input array and then traverse it to output the paths

Comment: No as it doesn't have any children folders under it so it is the lowest it can go.
For example there is no 
test plan/Regression/area 2/"subfodlers"

Comment: Hi @Daniel, please take a look at my solution when you have a chance. It works dynamically using a `do..while` loop to traverse from each deepest `innerpath` value to its highest `ancestor`. I thought it sensible to get a list of the deepest `innerpath` values first and then work backwards from there. Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: @Daniel **also worth noting that while I opted for a `do..while` loop, you could also use recursion here, though the `do..while` loop is cleaner in my opinion, as it doesn't create additional unnecessary function declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can simplify this a bit more by first creating a list of all unique `innerpath` values which do not also appear as `outerpath` values and then traversing backwards from each.

Here's how that would look, using your latest dynamic array of objects:

> I excluded the `id` property values from your original data, as it did not appear to be getting used anywhere, just for the sake of keeping this example concise, but you can certainly add that back in your final version.

```js
const data = [
  { outerpath: "test plan", innerpath: "Regression" },
  { outerpath: "Regression", innerpath: "area 1" },
  { outerpath: "area 1", innerpath: "Subarea 1" },
  { outerpath: "area 1", innerpath: "Subarea 2" },
  { outerpath: "Regression", innerpath: "area 2" },
  { outerpath: "test plan", innerpath: "other testing" },
  { outerpath: "other testing", innerpath: "other testing area 1" },
  { outerpath: "other testing", innerpath: "other testing area 2" },
  { outerpath: "other testing area 2", innerpath: "other testing subarea 1" },
  { outerpath: "Subarea 2", innerpath: "SubSubArea 1" }
];

const outerpaths = data.map(({ outerpath }) => outerpath),
      innerpaths = data.map(({ innerpath }) => innerpath).filter(innerpath => !outerpaths.includes(innerpath));

const concatenated = innerpaths.map(innerpath => {
  let obj = data.find(obj => obj.innerpath === innerpath),
      str = obj.outerpath + '/' + innerpath;
  if (obj) do {
    obj = data.find(({ innerpath }) => obj.outerpath === innerpath);
    if (obj) str = obj.outerpath + '/' + str;
  } while (obj)
  return str;
});

console.log(concatenated.join('\n'));
```

The output of this code is:

```html
test plan/Regression/area 1/Subarea 1
test plan/Regression/area 2
test plan/other testing/other testing area 1
test plan/other testing/other testing area 2/other testing subarea 1
test plan/Regression/area 1/Subarea 2/SubSubArea 1
```

Comment: Hi Brandon McConnell - Thank you for this it works like a charm :)

Comment: @Daniel glad to hear it! Lmk if you run into any issues with this 

Comment: is there any chance to expand on this answer. Once the concatenation array is finished to then match this to another array then use that row from the concat array in the new array.

For example:
`Concat Array = 
test plan/Regression/area 2
test plan/other testing/other testing area 1
test plan/other testing/other testing area 2/other testing subarea 1
test plan/Regression/area 1/Subarea 2/SubSubArea 1`

then the second array has a value `testSuiteName: "other testing subarea 1",` which we would need to mach to the concat array then set a value is array 2 with the correct info.

Comment: for example if concatenation matches `testSuiteName`  then do something.....
Possibly along the lines of this: 
`if(concatenation.map() ***Something***)
{
parentpath = concatenation.values();
Array2.Push({
parentSuiteName:parentpath.toString(),})
}`

Something like this. However this might be completely wrong so some advice would be very useful. @ Brandon

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```js
const array = [{ id: "Top Level", outerpath: "test plan", innerpath: "Regression" },
{ id: "other level", outerpath: "Regression", innerpath: "area 1" },
{ id: "Level 1", outerpath: "area 1", innerpath: "Subarea 1" },
{ id: "Level 1", outerpath: "area 1", innerpath: "Subarea 2" },
{ id: "Level 1", outerpath: "Regression", innerpath: "area 2" }]

const obj = {}; // a map of all our paths
const topLevel = array.splice(0, 1)[0]; // removing the top level from array as it is not needed, and for further reference
const base = `${topLevel.outerpath}/${topLevel.innerpath}`; // creating our default path, which we will use as a reference later

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    const path = array[i].outerpath.split(' '); // creating a unique key for our map
    const key = path[1] ? path[1] : path[0];
    if (!obj[key]) obj[key] = [];
    if (path[0] == 'area')
        obj[key].push(`${base}/${array[i].outerpath}/${array[i].innerpath}`);
    else if (path[0] == 'Regression')
        obj[key].push(`${base}/${array[i].innerpath}`)
}

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: AnanthDev - While this works for a static array my array is dynamic depending or the result I get back in the API request in the background so can't hard code the if statements with a static reference. it needs to by dynamic too.

If innerpath = outerpath sort of thing.